# How to store multiple values in a struct array using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, datareader

I'd like to populate an User array with data from my SQL Server database using a `SqlDataReader`.

This is my code so far:

```
public struct User
{
    public int id;
    public string log;
    public string password;

    public User (int id1,string s, s2)
    {
        id=id1;
        log =s;
        password=s2;
    }
}

User[] al = new User[50];
int i=0;

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("string")
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select [UserName], [Password]. from [TaUser]", connection);

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // populate the al array with the datas from the 3 columns : ID, UserName, Password
        }
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

I know that if I had a simple arraylist I could just do `al.Add("")`, however, I struggle when it comes to struct arrays.

Comment: Save it to `List<User>` with `.Add` and then call `.ToArray()` to get array from list

Comment: Your struct doesn't have the same fields as your query. There is no `UserName` field in the struct, for example; instead it has a mysterious field named `log`. Is this intentional? Also, your query returns two columns, but the constructor for `User` requires 3 arguments. What is going on here?

Comment: @JohnWu Not an uncommon case to have different property names in different domains imo

Comment: I'd suggest you make that immutable with read-only properties because muteable structs will cause you many headaches.  Better yet just make it a class as it doesn't really make sense as a struct in the first place.

Comment: @dan Fine if they’re different, but OP needs to specify the mapping, especially if there are more properties than columns.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lots of errors in your code.

First, your User constructor is invalid, it should be:

```
public User(int id1, string s, string s2)
```

Second, your query does not return user id.

Third, it would probably be better to use List instead of array.

With all that, this should work

```
List<User> userList = new List<User>() ;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("string")
{
connection.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select [Id], [UserName], [Password]. from [TaUser]", connection);

using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var id = reader.GetInt32(0);
        var userName = reader.GetString(1);
        var pwd = reader.GetString(2);
        var user = new User(id, userName, pwd);
        userList.Add(user);
    }
}
connection.Close();

// if you really need an array, do it here
var al = userList.ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise doing something like this:

```
SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Load(dataReader);
```

Then read out of that DataTable like this:

```
string name = dataTable.Rows[0]["UserName"] as string;
```

Then fill your User struct with the gathered info.  Job Done?